# Add JSON data Into HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to place JSON data into a HTML element dynamically. I am looping over the Dataset but its not going inside the loop. Please help.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Menu.asmx/MasterMenu")%>',
  data: [],
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    //var dataset = JSON.stringify(response.d);
    var dataset = response.d;
    alert(dataset);
    debugger;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      alert(dataset[i].MENU_NAME);
    }

    //  $.each(data, function (key, value{ <- this is wrong
    $.each(response.d, function(i, item) {
      alert("in");
      $("#menuDynamic").append("<li class='treeview'> <a href='#'> <i class='fa fa-dashboard'></i> <span>" + item.MENU_NAME + "</span> <span class='pull-right-container'><i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i> </span></a> </li>");
    });
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
    alert(response.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: There could be any number of reasons this isn't working. Have you attempted to debug it at all? Is the request sent? Is it successful? What's the response? Are there errors in the console? Help us to help you.

Comment: its successful data are retrieve in JSON string formate .

Comment: Maybe you could `console.log` instead of `alert`... that would help your development

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your success fn. May be your response is not JSON.

`response = $.parseJSON(response);`
             or 
`response = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: i have stringify that Response object and than i have to Place data into Element

Comment: if i stringify than it will Show Single Charecter for Each loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes Solved

```
$.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Menu.asmx/MasterMenu")%>', 
          data: [],
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {

             var data = JSON.parse((response.d));
              //var dataset = JSON.stringify(response.d);
              //var dataset =   $.parseJSON(response);

              debugger;


              $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                  $("#menuDynamic").append("<li class='treeview'> <a href='#'> <i class='fa fa-dashboard'></i> <span>" + item.MENU_NAME + "</span> <span class='pull-right-container'><i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i> </span></a> </li>");

              });
          }, error: function (response) {
              alert(response.responseText);
              alert(response.statusText);

          }

      });
```

Comment: but you're still using `alert`

Comment: I know that. But do you know what `console.log` does? It does the same, only much, _MUCH_ better and in an unobtrusive way. `alert` is prehistoric.

Comment: yeah i know alert popup the Result with popup window and console print the result on console window .

Comment: Hey looking for job in outside India. help me if any Vacancy are there :)